# Finding prime isn't working

Tags: c#

> **Warning:** Simple homework assignment, no idea what I'm doing

So, I'm trying to make a program that finds the first prime numbers from 1 to 100 and prints them in a listbox. This is my code:

```
private bool IsPrime(int number)
{
    int count;
    if (number == 2)
        return true;
    for (count = 3; count < number; count = count + 2)
    {
        if (number % count == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int number;
    for (number = 1; number < 100; number = number++)
        if (IsPrime(number))
            primeList.Items.Add(number);
}
```

And the program isn't catching any syntax errors, but it also freezes up every time I try to run it. Any idea why this happens? Thanks.

Comment: Does it throw any exceptions? If it freezes up and doesn't throw an exception it means that your code is taking a long time to run.

Comment: try with fewer numbers for (number=1; number<10; number++)

Comment: Ah, that might work. I'll give that a shot...

Comment: @bryanmac [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated?cb=1)

Comment: Bah, even with 10 it doesn't finish running. Which is weird, because doing the math for that few numbers should be nothing. I haven't caught in in an infinite loop or something, have I?

Comment: put a breakpoint in the loop and you will find out

Comment: Finding primes is a common programming application (at least a challenge) Theirs a lot of answers on Stack that pertain to this.

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you have a special check for the number 2? 2 > 3 == false so skip the for loop and return true?

Comment: You know, that does make sense. I'm guessing I started out thinking I'd need to make an exception for 2, then wrote the for loop and forgot about the 2 sitting up there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use:

```
for (number = 1; number < 100; number = number++)
```

while you should write

```
 for (number = 1; number < 100; number++)
```

You should read these articles to understand why your original code didn't increment the : [for](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx), [++ Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w.aspx)

You can learn the behaivour of the `++` operator in some test code:

```
        int n = 0;
        Console.WriteLine(n); //0
        n = n++;
        Console.WriteLine(n); //0
        n = ++n;
        Console.WriteLine(n); //1 
        n = n++;
        Console.WriteLine(n); //1
        n = ++n;
        Console.WriteLine(n); //2
```

Another nice example would be:

```
        int n = 0;
        int x = n++;
        int y = ++n;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("x={0}", x)); //0
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("y={0}", y)); //2
        Console.WriteLine(x + y); //n++ + ++n == 0 + 2 == 2
        n = 0;
        x = ++n;
        y = n++;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("x={0}", x)); //1
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("y={0}", y)); //1
        Console.WriteLine(x + y); //++n + n++ == 1 + 1 == 2
```

Comment: Wow, yeah. That was it. Thanks, I feel dumb.